# using '\' instead of '/' for folder separator in mingw

Tags: mingw

I'd like to use '\' for folder separator in mingw.

for example, 'cd c:\work' not 'cd c:/work'

Can I use '\' instead of '/' for folder seperator in mingw?

Comment: when seperator count is one, always '\' and '/' works good.
when more than one, '/' seperator works good always.
   for example> $ cd c:/work/xxx
When more than one, '\' seperator need ''.
   for example> $ cd c:\work\xxx
           ERR: sh: cd: c:workxxx: No such file or directory 
   for example> $ cd 'c:\work\xxx'             : WORKS GOOD

Comment: I understood my mistake.